# How should I delete a field with the Profiles library

Tags: google-apps-script

Suppose you have a complete user entry with al details like department, company name, job title, some custom fields, etc.

How should we delete a field or leave it blank; for example, I if I try to leave blank company name to delete it, I get a "Cannot call method "setCompanyName" of null, so how should deletion of this information should be managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single value fields like Department, CompanyName etc you can set the value to an empty string (not null) to remove the existing value. For example:

```
profile.setCompanyName('');
```

For custom fields, use [`.deleteCustomeField()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/custom-field#deleteCustomField%28%29) and fields for which there can be multiple instances use the provided delete methods like [`.deletePhoneField()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/phone-field#deletePhoneField%28%29). Use them like this:

```
var phones =  profile.getPhones();
for (var i in phones) {
  phones[i].deletePhoneField();
}
```

The [ProfilesApp Tests](https://script.google.com/d/1uIal206aOFZvmOSsTcZPgRXptPSZHciJoIztKSrM8JYCYGb-tQ0MA2m_/edit?usp=drive_web) script has examples of all these in unit tests.

Comment: Great Peter, thank you for the quick reply. I didn't realized there was a test file; that's a great piece of documentation you have there.